# Infection probability in a markovian complete graph

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, network

There is a complete graph, there are $n$ infected people out of a total of $N$. Every period, every infected person has some probability, $p$ of spreading to each of his neighbors(everyone who isn't infected since its a complete graph).

If there are $n$ infected people out of $N$, what is the probability that there are $x$ people are infected next period ($x>n$)?

I had in the past posted something similar which was completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1,\dots, N-n$ let $B_i$ be iid random variables with Bernoulli distribution with parameter: $$r:=1-(1-p)^n$$

Here $N-n$ corresponds with the number of uninfected persons and $r$ is the probability that such a person will be infected during the period.

Then the number of persons that are infected after the period can be written as:$$X=n+\sum_{i=1}^{N-n}B_i$$

Here $\sum_{i=1}^{N-n}B_i$ has binomial distribution with parameters $N-n$ and $r$.

Based on that we can find: $$P(X=x)=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N-n}B_i=x-n\right)=\binom{N-n}{x-n}r^{x-n}(1-r)^{N-x}$$

Comment: It's unclear to me if this takes into account all the possibilities. For N=4 and n=2, there seem to be numerous cases for going to three.

1 infects 3. 1 Infects 4, 1 and 2 infect 3, 1 and 2 infect 4, 2 infects 3, 2 infects 4.

@drhab

Comment: Do you agree that in the example in your comment person 3 has probability  $1-(1-p)^2$ to be infected? I.e. $1$ minus the probability that the persons 1 and 2 both do not infect him?

Comment: Hm I think you are right! Makes sense thanks!